# How to get index of object in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js

I tryed to get `indexOf` `object` which is in observable array (`Knockout`).
What I tryed to do show this simple example:

```
    var arrayObjectIndexOf = function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
};
    var sampleArray = [{ItemID: "2", ItemName: "name1"}, {ItemID: "3", ItemName: "name2"}]
    sampleArray: ko.observableArray();
    arrayObjectIndexOf(sampleArray(), "2", "ItemID"); // it's always returns me -1 but should in this sample return index equal to 0
```

`myArray[i][property]` it's returns function not really value to compare to.

The Question is how can I make it work as it should?

If something isn't clear here please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ko.unwrap` (or `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` if you are using an older version of KO) to make sure that you are always working with the underlying values and not with the observables:

```
var arrayObjectIndexOf = function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
    var unwrappedArray = ko.unwrap(myArray);
    for (var i = 0, len = unwrappedArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (ko.unwrap(unwrappedArray[i][property]) === searchTerm) return i;
    }
    return -1;
};
```